# How to implement Active Record inheritance in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, inheritance, activerecord, model

How to implement inheritance with active records?

For example, I want a class Animal, class Dog, and class Cat.

How would the model and the database table mapping be?

Comment: you might want to accept an answer

Answer (score 67):

Rails supports Single Table Inheritance.

From the [AR docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html):

> Active Record allows inheritance by
>   storing the name of the class in a
>   column that by default is named "type"
>   (can be changed by overwriting
>   Base.inheritance_column). This means
>   that an inheritance looking like this:
>
> ```
> class Company < ActiveRecord::Base; end   
> class Firm < Company; end  
> class Client < Company; end   
> class PriorityClient < Client; end
> ```
>
> When you do Firm.create(:name =>
>   "37signals"), this record will be
>   saved in the companies table with type
>   = "Firm". You can then fetch this row again using Company.find(:first, "name
>   = ‘37signals’") and it will return a Firm object.
>
> If you don‘t have a type column
>   defined in your table, single-table
>   inheritance won‘t be triggered. In
>   that case, it‘ll work just like normal
>   subclasses with no special magic for
>   differentiating between them or
>   reloading the right type with find.

A pretty good tutorial is here: http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/03/rails-single-table-inheritance/

Answer (score 17):

Models:

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base; end
class Dog < Animal; end
class Cat < Animal; end
```

Migration:

```
class CreateAnimals < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :animals do |t|
      # Other attributes...
      t.string :type
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :animals
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

ActiveRecord supports mapping inheritance hierarchies to a single table([Single-table inheritance](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/). Table would have a column `type` which stores name of actual class and is used to select other class-specific columns.

It is possible to implement multi-table inheritance mapping, as shown [here](http://lindsaar.net/2008/3/12/multi-table-inheritance-in-rails-when-two-tables-are-one), but this particular way is not portable, AFAIK.

Comment: This is now possible with rails out of the box, using [delegated types](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/DelegatedType.html)

Answer (score 1):

#### Delegated Types

One particular way of doing this is via [Delegated Types](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/DelegatedType.html) - this makes sense **only if you want to paginate all animals together**, and to view cats and dogs together, then the delegated type is particularly useful. I also like it because you don't need to have empty columns, for where it doesn't make sense, as is the case with Single Table Inheritance solutions.

```
# Schema: entries[ id, created_at, updated_at, animalable_type, animalable_id ]  

class Animal < ApplicationRecord
  delegated_type :animalable, types: %w[ Cat Dog ]
end

module Animalable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_one :animal, as: :animalable, touch: true
  end
end

# Schema: cats[ id, selfishness_level ]
class Cat < ApplicationRecord
  include Animalable
end

# Schema: dogs[ id, favourite_game, wag_tail_level ]
class Dog < ApplicationRecord
  include Animalable
end
```