# Retrieving an object from two joinable tables in Active Record

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a situation where I have a SQL table which pretty much 'parents' others.
It is easiest to imagine in the example below where there are different types of clients (which need different fields of data to be stored) that all have a unique client ID.

```
CREATE TABLE clients (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  internal_ref character varying,
  address character varying,
  telephone_no character varying,
  CONSTRAINT pkey_clients PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT uniq_clients_internal_ref UNIQUE (internal_ref)
)

CREATE TABLE partnerships (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  clients_id integer,
  name character varying,
  CONSTRAINT pkey_partnerships PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fkey_partnerships_clients_id FOREIGN KEY (clients_id)
    REFERENCES clients(id) MATCH FULL
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

CREATE TABLE individuals (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  clients_id integer,
  forename character varying,
  surname character varying,
  CONSTRAINT pkey_individuals PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fkey_individuals_clients_id FOREIGN KEY (clients_id)
    REFERENCES clients(id) MATCH FULL
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

I'm new to Active Record and not sure how (or if) I can elegantly implement it, so that I can find a business and I get the joined client data.

Currently I am trying:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
end
class Partnership < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :clients
end

output = Partnership.find(:all) # I only have one row in both tables, which is also joinable
p output # => [#<Partnership id: 1, name: "PART1", clients_id: 1>]
```

I need `output` to also have the joinable data, such as `internal_ref`, `address` etc. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy. Your "child" models `belongs_to` "parent" model which can `has_one` or `has_many` "children"

Models:

```
# app/models/client.rb
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :partnership
  has_one :individual
end

# app/models/pertnership.rb
class Partnership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end

# app/models/individual.rb
class Individual < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end
```

Controller:

```
@output = Partnerships.all
```

If you don't want to make additional query each time you try to access the Client you use eager loading:

```
@output = Partnerships.includes(:client).all
```

Or eager loading with both client and individual:

```
@output = Partnerships.includes(:client => :individual ).all
```

Then, in your view, you can easily access referenced client or even individual referenced in client.

```
<% @output.each do |partnership| %>
  <%= partneship.client.internal_ref %>
  <%= partneship.client.address %>
  <%= partneship.client.individual.forname %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not in a position to test this yet. Assuming it works, I'll accept it later. I'm curious about the `<%` syntax. Is that a rails thing? I'm just using normal Ruby with the active_record gem.

Comment: Kinda. It's ERB view syntax. I have assumed you are using Rails since you want to use ActiveRecord. You can write @output in console pretty much the same way, just loose the `<%(|) ... %>`.

Comment: I tried this, but for whatever reason, could not get it to return the client part of `partnership.client`. Your answer helped me understand Active Record a bit better, but upon further investigation, I have found AR doesn't seem to support the way I was wanting to do it (or at least there's not enough documentation for me to fall back on), so I'm just going to use a single table inheritance, as discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598936/how-to-implement-active-record-inheritance-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: I have updated answer with fast and dirty code demo. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks for your continued effort. That works. As a clarification, a Client may only link to a Partnership OR an Individual (they are types of client) - I was able to adjust the script to emulate that scenario. I think I will now go down the "single table inheritance" route (it works well with the other things I'm doing in my app), but this approach will probably be better in most circumstances.