# How would you model different post types in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am stuck.  I am trying to create an app in Rails 3 that allows Users to create a Post, which is either a Image, Photo, or Text.  I want my Posts index to show all three types of posts and to create a "publisher" that allows the User to create ONE OF an Image, Photo, or Text Post.  I have tried everything, including STI and has_one relationships, but nothing seems to come out in an Rails-optimized way and it's driving me crazy!  There must be something I'm missing.  Please help!

Comment: Did you have any success with this?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you want to have a post type that has many posts

Your types table and model

```
  Types Table
| id  |   type  |
| 1   |  image  |
| 2   |  photo  |
| 3   |  text   |

class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts
end
```

Then your posts table and model

```
Post Table
|  id  | name | content | type_id | user_id |

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :types
  belongs_to :users
end
```

So when you make your query you can say:
Type.include(:posts).find(1)

Answer (score 0):

Check this

[How to implement Active Record inheritance in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1598936/517483)

http://mediumexposure.com/multiple-table-inheritance-active-record/