# How do I create and test environment-specific code?

Tags: ruby, testing, sinatra

I have a web app that hopes to track/write bills from different state legislatures. The problem I found, though, is that many states have different rules regarding bill schema, rules for progression (i.e. some states allow you to reconsider a failed bill while others do not), et cetera.

How I'm handling it right now in my models is to create a `Bill` class and then conditionally reopen the class and add additional fields and validations to the class, depending on environment variables. The intent is for each state to have its own installation of the app, so I would have one with `STATE` set to `OR` and make the app use Oregon bill rules.

This has become a huge problem for me, however. Re-opening the class like this works well enough in production, but it becomes really hard to test because the class needs to be opened up at startup and can't be disabled for testing unless I somehow reload the entire program with a different environment variable. I've searched through Google and StackOverflow, but I haven't gotten any results for best practices of what I'm looking for, either because they don't exist or I don't know the name for it.

Comment: Looks like a problem for good old-fashioned class inheritance? Good answer for how to use it with ActiveRecord here, if having a different Model behaviour per state is what has led to your unusual code structure - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598936/how-to-implement-active-record-inheritance-in-ruby-on-rails - everything else would just be normal Ruby for class inheritance, including splitting up your tests (into tests for base class and polymorphic features/behaviour, and tests for state-specific behaviour of sub-classes)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking about environment variables, why not use environment variables?

`ENV` can be the way to do this, just add the appropriate state in there.

```
>> ENV['State_Code'] = 'FL'
=> "FL"
>> ENV['State_Code']
=> "FL"
```

Change it as you want to test the different rules.

This has the advantage of being able to be set from outside of your application, as `ENV` is read from your environment, not surprisingly.

Comment: This could be done in a `Rakefile` that used a test naming convention to set environment for state-specific tests before running them. Or just had a coded lookup list.