# Rails Multiple relationships and STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, sti

Iam setting up user accounts and users have different roles. Iam using STI and my models look like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

end

Class Teacher < User

end

Class Student < User

end
```

How can i set up a many to many relationship between Students and Teachers so that i can do calls like,

`Teacher.students` or `Student.teachers` ??

Teac

Comment: instead of using STI, you should rethink your layout and maybe choose composition over inheritance. e.g. a model `User` and then `Teacher#belongs_to :user` and `Student#belongs_to :user`

Comment: Thanks, Iam thought about it though STI was making alot of semantic meaning. Will consider it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement Active Record inheritance in Ruby on Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598936/how-to-implement-active-record-inheritance-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598936/how-to-implement-active-record-inheritance-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: @Oxynum This is not a duplicate, that question describes how to setup STI relationship. I have done that my problem is that i cant set up a relationship between the subclassess. In that question it would be a relationship like Firm.clients

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting aside the 'whether or not to use STI?' question and assuming you have a reason.

You'll need an id column of course, eg teacher_id.

I'm going to include explicit class names in my example because I know it works, but I probably only need them because my models are namespaced, so they are probably superfluous for you.

```
class Teacher < User
  has_many :students, :class_name => 'Student', :foreign_key => 'teacher_id'
end

class Student < User
  belongs_to :teacher, :class_name => 'Teacher', :foreign_key => 'teacher_id'
end
```

And that should do it---dang.  That would do it except I missed many-to-many.

So I'd try HABTM, but I confess I've never actually done this with STI.

Start with this migration to make join table.

```
class CreateStudentsAndTeachers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :students_teachers do |t|
      t.belongs_to :student
      t.belongs_to :teacher
    end
  end
end
```

And then this should work (and again, you may well not need the specified class name)

```
class Teacher < User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students, :class_name => 'Student'
end

class Student < User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teachers, :class_name => 'Teacher'
end
```

Comment: Ooops--I missed the many-to-many part.  Have you already tried a HABTM?  I'd expect that to work based on the smooth sailing I've had with other STI effects, but I don't believe I've actually tested that.

Comment: the problem is that i dont have teacher_id i only have user_id

Comment: The user_id is the record identifier.  If you want one-to-many self join in STI you'll also need the 'foreign' id column (eg teacher_id).  If you want many-to-many via HABTM you won't need another column, but you will need the join table.