# Converting Instance Variables in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm building a simple crm. I'm trying to convert an @lead to an @customer after they become an actual customer. In the lead show page I'd like to have a button that says convert to customer, but I'm unsure how to do this in the controller and model.

What should I do?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If one record has to become another you need some model code that takes a Lead and converts it to a Customer. I don't see any code here, no example of what fields are being manipulated, not even a hint, so it's anyone's guess how you might do this. I normally do it with an instance method on the originating model, like `@lead.to_customer` returns a Customer instance you can save.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, some code would be really nice. 
Second, your problem sounds a little bit like you need inheritance. Then you can have something like the following:

```
class Lead
  ... 
end

class Customer < Lead
   ... # this is your customer, having all the properties of a lead but as well new ones.
end
```

To transfer one `lead` to a `customer` you can then use [becomes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/becomes) to transfer between them. From your tags I can see, that you are using Ruby on Rails, so you want to have a look at single table inheritance [STI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598936/how-to-implement-active-record-inheritance-in-ruby-on-rails).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. I will give that a try. I didn't have any sample code because I haven't started the conversion process yet. But I will look into inheritance. Thanks again!

Comment: If that answers your question, feel free to accept it. Happy to help!